# Using ranking data in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn

I will be putting the max bounty on this as I am struggling to learn these concepts! I am trying to use some ranking data in a logistic regression. I want to use machine learning to make a simple classifier as to whether a webpage is "good" or not. It's just a learning exercise so I don't expect great results; just hoping to learn the "process" and coding techniques.

I have put my data in a .csv as follows :

```
URL WebsiteText AlexaRank GooglePageRank
```

In my Test CSV we have :

```
URL WebsiteText AlexaRank GooglePageRank Label
```

Label is a binary classification indicating "good" with 1 or "bad" with 0.

I currently have my LR running using only the website text; which I run a TF-IDF on.

I have a two questions which I need help with. I'll be putting a max bounty on this question and awarding it to the best answer as this is something I'd like some good help with so I, and others, may learn.

- How can I normalize my ranking data for AlexaRank? I have a set of
  10,000 webpages, for which I have the Alexa rank of all of them;
  however they aren't ranked `1-10,000`. They are ranked out of the
  entire Internet, so while `http://www.google.com` may be ranked `#1`,
  `http://www.notasite.com` may be ranked `#83904803289480`. How do I
  normalize this in Scikit learn in order to get the best possible
  results from my data?
- I am running my Logistic Regression in this way; I am nearly sure I have done this incorrectly. I am trying to do the TF-IDF on the website text, then add the two other relevant columns and fit the Logistic Regression. I'd appreciate if someone could quickly verify that I am taking in the three columns I want to use in my LR correctly. Any and all feedback on how I can improve myself would also be appreciated here.

  ```
  loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')

  print "loading data.."
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2])#Reading WebsiteText column for TF-IDF.
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('test.tsv'))[:,2])
  y = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,-1] #reading label

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word',

  token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1, smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)

  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, C=1, fit_intercept=True,    intercept_scaling=1.0, class_weight=None, random_state=None)

  X_all = traindata + testdata
  lentrain = len(traindata)

  print "fitting pipeline"
  tfv.fit(X_all)
  print "transforming data"
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)
  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]

  print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))

  #Add Two Integer Columns
  AlexaAndGoogleTrainData = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[2:,3])#Not sure if I am doing this correctly. Expecting it to contain AlexaRank and GooglePageRank columns.
  AlexaAndGoogleTestData = list(np.array(p.read_table('test.tsv'))[2:,3])
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaAndGoogleTestData + AlexaAndGoogleTrainData

  #Add two columns to X.
  X = np.append(X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo, 1) #Think I have done this incorrectly.

  print "training on full data"
  rd.fit(X,y)
  pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
  testfile = p.read_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
  pred_df = p.DataFrame(pred, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
  pred_df.to_csv('benchmark.csv')
      print "submission file created.."`
  ```

Thank you very much for all feedback - please post if you need any further information!

Comment: Just take the log of the rank. That brings it down to the typical range of term frequency features, and it's more numerically stable than mean-centering. You can still standardize/normalize afterwards.

Comment: There is no Label column in your train file? Typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` would be the first thing you want to try. StandardScaler transforms all of your features into Mean-0-Std-1 features.

- This definitely gets rid of your first problem. `AlexaRank` will be guaranteed to be spread around 0 and bounded. (Yes, even massive `AlexaRank` values like `83904803289480` are transformed to small floating point numbers). Of course, the results will not be integers between `1` and `10000` but they will maintain same order as the original ranks. And in this case, keeping the rank bounded and normalized will help solve your second problem like follows.
- In order to understand why normalization would help in LR, let's revisit the logit formulation of LR. 
  [image]
  In your case, X1, X2, X3 are three TF-IDF features and X4, X5 are Alexa/Google rank related features. Now, the linear form of equation suggest that the coefficients represent the change in logit of y with *one unit* change in a variable. Think what happens when your X4 is kept fixed at a massive rank value, say `83904803289480`. In that case, the Alexa Rank variable *dominates* your LR fit and a small change in TF-IDF value has almost no effect on the LR fit. Now one might think that the coefficient should be able to adjust to small/large values to account for differences between these features. Not in this case --- It's not only the magnitude of variables that matter but also their *range*. Alexa Rank definitely has a large range and should definitely dominate your LR fit in this case. Therefore, I guess normalizing all variables using StandardScaler to adjust their range will improve the fit.

Here is how you can scale the `X` matrix.

```
sc = proprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X = sc.transform(X)
```

Don't forget to use same scaler to transform `X_test`.

```
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Now you can use the fitting procedure etc.

```
rd.fit(X, y)
re.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Check this out for more on sklearn preprocessing: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

**Edit:** Parsing and column merging part can be easily done using pandas, i.e., there is no need to convert the matrices into list and then append them. Moreover, pandas dataframes can be directly indexed by their column names.

```
AlexaAndGoogleTrainData = p.read_table('train.tsv', header=0)[["AlexaRank", "GooglePageRank"]]
AlexaAndGoogleTestData = p.read_table('test.tsv', header=0)[["AlexaRank", "GooglePageRank"]]
AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaAndGoogleTestData.append(AlexaAndGoogleTrainData)
```

Note that we are passing `header=0` argument to read_table to maintain original header names from tsv file. And also note how we can index using entire set of columns. Finally, you can *stack* this new matrix with `X` using `numpy.hstack`.

```
X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
```

`hstack` horizontally combined two multi-dimensional array-like structures provided their lengths are same.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer; really informative and educational. I really appreciate it! Just one simple question further - how can I combine my TF-IDF numpy array with my numpy array containing my ranked values. I have tried to do this in my code but I believe I have done it completely incorrectly unfortunately. Thank you very much, +1.

Comment: I've edited the response to address indexing/appending issues.

Comment: bounty please? :) just kidding

Comment: Dont worry I'll add it when it's eligible! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding normalizing the numeric ranks either scikit `StandardScaler` or a logarithmic transform (or both) should work well enough.

For building up a working pipeline, I find my sanity greatly benefits from using the Pandas package and the `sklearn.pipeline` utilities. Here is a simple script that should do what you need.

First a couple of utlitlty classes I always seem to need. It would be nice to have something like these in `sklearn.pipeline` or `sklearn.utilities`.

```
from sklearn import base
class Columns(base.TransformerMixin, base.BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        super(Columns, self).__init__()
        self.columns_ = columns
    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
        return X[self.columns_]

class Text(base.TransformerMixin, base.BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
        return (X.apply("\t".join, axis=1, raw=False))
```

Now set up the pipeline.
I used  the `SGDClassifier` implementation of logistic regression since it tends to be more eficcient for high dimensional data like text classification also I usually find that hinge loss usually gives better results than logistic regression anyway.

```
from sklearn import linear_model as lin
from sklearn import  metrics
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text as txt
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing as prep
import numpy as np
from pandas.io import parsers
import pandas as pd

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('feat', FeatureUnion([
        ('txt', Pipeline([
            ('txtcols', Columns(["WebsiteText"])),
            ('totxt', Text()),
            ('vect', txt.TfidfVectorizer()),
            ])),
        ('num', Pipeline([
            ('numcols', Columns(["AlexaRank", "GooglePageRank"])),
            ('scale', prep.StandardScaler()),
            ])),
        ])),
    ('clf', lin.SGDClassifier(loss="log")),
    ])
```

Next train the model:

```
train=parsers.read_csv("train.csv")
pipe.fit(train, train.Label)
```

Finally evaluate on test data:

```
test=parsers.read_csv("test.csv")
tstlbl=np.array(test.Label)

print pipe.score(test, tstlbl)

pred = pipe.predict(test)
print metrics.confusion_matrix(tstlbl, pred)
print metrics.classification_report(tstlbl, pred)
print metrics.f1_score(tstlbl, pred)

prob = pipe.decision_function(test)
print metrics.roc_auc_score(tstlbl, prob)
print metrics.average_precision_score(tstlbl, prob)
```

You will probably not get very good results with everything using default setting like this,
but it should give you a working baseline to work from. I can suggest some parameter settings that usually work for me if you like.