# Joining columns in pandas incorrectly

Tags: python, csv, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running TF-IDF on a single column. I want to use this TF-IDF and another scaled integer column to train my Logistic Regression classifier.

Unfortunately I am running into problems doing this as I am just beginning in machine-learning. The code currently has a bug, but the bigger issue is that I am simply unsure how to join the two features together and what is best practice here. How can I get this running ?

```
  from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  import sklearn.preprocessing
  import sklearn.linear_model as lm
  import pandas as p
  loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=',')

  print "loading data.."
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])#reading text column to make tf-idf
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])
  y = np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,-2] #reading our labels
  AlexaTrainData = p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]] #reading integer columns
  AlexaTestData = p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]]
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaTestData.append(AlexaTrainData) #joining integer columns

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)

  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None)

  X_all = traindata + testdata #joining tf-idf columns
  lentrain = len(traindata)

  print "fitting pipeline"
  tfv.fit(X_all)
  print "transforming data"
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all) #running TF-IDF

  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]
  X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
  sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
  X = sc.transform(X)
  X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
    
  print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))

  print "training on full data"
  rd.fit(X,y)
  pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
  testfile = p.read_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
  pred_df = p.DataFrame(pred, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
  pred_df.to_csv('benchmark.csv')
  print "submission file created.."
```

Currently the code dies with the following error :

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Extract from FinalCSVFin.csv :

```
url;urlid;boilerplate;label;alexarank;;;;
http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2010-12-23/ibm-predicts-holographic-calls-air-breathing-batteries-by-2015.html;4042;"{""title"":""IBM Sees Holographic Calls Air Breathing Batteries ibm sees holographic calls, air-breathing batteries"",""body"":""A sign stands outside the International Business Machines Corp IBM Almaden Research Center campus in San Jose California Photographer Tony Avelar Bloomberg Buildings stand at the International Business Machines Corp IBM Almaden Research Center campus in the Santa Teresa Hills of San Jose California Photographer Tony Avelar Bloomberg By 2015 your mobile phone will project a 3 D image of anyone who calls and your laptop will be powered by kinetic energy At least that s what International Business Machines Corp sees in its crystal ball The predictions are part of an annual tradition for the Armonk New York based company which surveys its 3 000 researchers to find five ideas expected to take root in the next five years IBM the world s largest provider of computer services looks to Silicon Valley for input gleaning many ideas from its Almaden research center in San Jose California Holographic conversations projected from mobile phones lead this year s list The predictions also include air breathing batteries computer programs that can tell when and where traffic jams will take place environmental information generated by sensors in cars and phones and cities powered by the heat thrown off by computer servers These are all stretch goals and that s good said Paul Saffo managing director of foresight at the investment advisory firm Discern in San Francisco In an era when pessimism is the new black a little dose of technological optimism is not a bad thing For IBM it s not just idle speculation The company is one of the few big corporations investing in long range research projects and it counts on innovation to fuel growth Saffo said Not all of its predictions pan out though IBM was overly optimistic about the spread of speech technology for instance When the ideas do lead to products they can have broad implications for society as well as IBM s bottom line he said Research Spending They have continued to do research when all the other grand research organizations are gone said Saffo who is also a consulting associate professor at Stanford University IBM invested 5 8 billion in research and development last year 6 1 percent of revenue While that s down from about 10 percent in the early 1990s the company spends a bigger share on research than its computing rivals Hewlett Packard Co the top maker of personal computers spent 2 4 percent last year At Almaden scientists work on projects that don t always fit in with IBM s computer business The lab s research includes efforts to develop an electric car battery that runs 500 miles on one charge a filtration system for desalination and a program that shows changes in geographic data IBM rose 9 cents to 146 04 at 11 02 a m in New York Stock Exchange composite trading The stock had gained 11 percent this year before today Citizen Science The list is meant to give a window into the company s innovation engine said Josephine Cheng a vice president at IBM s Almaden lab All this demonstrates a real culture of innovation at IBM and willingness to devote itself to solving some of the world s biggest problems she said Many of the predictions are based on projects that IBM has in the works One of this year s ideas that sensors in cars wallets and personal devices will give scientists better data about the environment is an expansion of the company s citizen science initiative Earlier this year IBM teamed up with the California State Water Resources Control Board and the City of San Jose Environmental Services to help gather information about waterways Researchers from Almaden created an application that lets smartphone users snap photos of streams and creeks and report back on conditions The hope is that these casual observations will help local and state officials who don t have the resources to do the work themselves Traffic Predictors IBM also sees data helping shorten commutes in the next five years Computer programs will use algorithms and real time traffic information to predict which roads will have backups and how to avoid getting stuck Batteries may last 10 times longer in 2015 than today IBM says Rather than using the current lithium ion technology new models could rely on energy dense metals that only need to interact with the air to recharge Some electronic devices might ditch batteries altogether and use something similar to kinetic wristwatches which only need to be shaken to generate a charge The final prediction involves recycling the heat generated by computers and data centers Almost half of the power used by data centers is currently spent keeping the computers cool IBM scientists say it would be better to harness that heat to warm houses and offices In IBM s first list of predictions compiled at the end of 2006 researchers said instantaneous speech translation would become the norm That hasn t happened yet While some programs can quickly translate electronic documents and instant messages and other apps can perform limited speech translation there s nothing widely available that acts like the universal translator in Star Trek Second Life The company also predicted that online immersive environments such as Second Life would become more widespread While immersive video games are as popular as ever Second Life s growth has slowed Internet users are flocking instead to the more 2 D environments of Facebook Inc and Twitter Inc Meanwhile a 2007 prediction that mobile phones will act as a wallet ticket broker concierge bank and shopping assistant is coming true thanks to the explosion of smartphone applications Consumers can pay bills through their banking apps buy movie tickets and get instant feedback on potential purchases all with a few taps on their phones The nice thing about the list is that it provokes thought Saffo said If everything came true they wouldn t be doing their job To contact the reporter on this story Ryan Flinn in San Francisco at rflinn bloomberg net To contact the editor responsible for this story Tom Giles at tgiles5 bloomberg net by 2015, your mobile phone will project a 3-d image of anyone who calls and your laptop will be powered by kinetic energy. at least that\u2019s what international business machines corp. sees in its crystal ball."",""url"":""bloomberg news 2010 12 23 ibm predicts holographic calls air breathing batteries by 2015 html""}";0;345;;;;
http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2012-07/electronic-futuristic-starting-gun-eliminates-advantages-races;8471;"{""title"":""The Fully Electronic Futuristic Starting Gun That Eliminates Advantages in Races the fully electronic, futuristic starting gun that eliminates advantages in races the fully electronic, futuristic starting gun that eliminates advantages in races"",""body"":""And that can be carried on a plane without the hassle too The Omega E Gun Starting Pistol Omega It s easy to take for granted just how insanely close some Olympic races are and how much the minutiae of it all can matter The perfect example is the traditional starting gun Seems easy You pull a trigger and the race starts Boom What people don t consider When a conventional gun goes off the sound travels to the ears of the closest runner a fraction of a second sooner than the others That s just enough to matter and why the latest starting pistol has traded in the mechanical boom for orchestrated electronic noise Omega has been the watch company tasked as the official timekeeper of the Olympic Games since 1932 At the 2010 Vancouver games they debuted their new starting gun which is a far cry from the iconic revolvers associated with early games it s clearly electronic but still more than a button that s pressed to get the show rolling About as far away as you can get probably while still clearly being a starting gun Pull the trigger once and off the Olympians go If it s pressed twice consecutively it signals a false start Working through a speaker system is what eliminates any kind of advantage for athletes It s not a big advantage being close to a gun but the sound of the bullet traveling one meter every three milliseconds could contribute to a win Powder pistols have been connected to a speaker system before but even then runners could react to the sound of the real pistol firing rather than wait for the speaker sounds to reach them This year s setup will have speakers placed equidistant from runners forcing the sound to reach each competitor at exactly the same time It wouldn t be an enormous difference Omega Timing board member Peter H\u00fcrzeler said in an email but when you think about reaction times being measured in tiny fractions of a second placing a speaker behind each lane has eliminated any sort of advantage for any athlete They all hear the start commands and signal at exactly the same moment There s also an ulterior reason for its look In a post September 11th world a gun on its way to a major event is going to raise more than a few TSA eyebrows even if it s a realistic looking fake Rather than deal with that the e gun can be transported while still maintaining the general look of a starting gun But there s still nothing like hearing a starting gun go off at the start of a race more than signaling the runners there s probably some Pavlovian response after more than a century of Olympic games that make people want to hear the real thing not a whiny electronic noise Everyone in the stands at home thankfully will still be getting that The sound is programmable and can be synthesized to sound like almost anything H\u00fcrzeler says but we program it to sound like a pistol it s a way to use the best possible starting technology but to keep a rich tradition alive and that can be carried on a plane without the hassle, too technology,gadgets,london 2012,london olympics,olympics,omega,starting guns,summer olympics,timing,popular science,popsci"",""url"":""popsci technology article 2012 07 electronic futuristic starting gun eliminates advantages races""}";1;5304;;;;
http://www.menshealth.com/health/flu-fighting-fruits?cm_mmc=Facebook-_-MensHealth-_-Content-Health-_-FightFluWithFruit;1164;"{""title"":""Fruits that Fight the Flu fruits that fight the flu | cold & flu | men's health"",""body"":""Apples The most popular source of antioxidants in our diet one apple has an antioxidant effect equivalent to 1 500 mg of vitamin C Apples are loaded with protective flavonoids which may prevent heart disease and cancer Next Papayas With 250 percent of the RDA of vitamin C a papaya can help kick a cold right out of your system The beta carotene and vitamins C and E in papayas reduce inflammation throughout the body lessening the effects of asthma Next Cranberries Cranberries have more antioxidants than other common fruits and veggies One serving has five times the amount in broccoli Cranberries are a natural probiotic enhancing good bacteria levels in the gut and protecting it from foodborne illnesses Next Grapefruit Loaded with vitamin C grapefruit also contains natural compounds called limonoids which can lower cholesterol The red varieties are a potent source of the cancer fighting substance lycopene Next Bananas One of the top food sources of vitamin B6 bananas help reduce fatigue depression stress and insomnia Bananas are high in magnesium which keeps bones strong and potassium which helps prevent heart disease and high blood pressure Next everything you need to know about cold and flu so you don\u2019t get sick this season, at men\u2019s health.com cold, flu, infection, sore throat, sneeze, immunity, germs, allergies, stay healthy, sick, contagious, medicines, cold medicine"",""url"":""menshealth health flu fighting fruits cm mmc Facebook Mens Health Content Health Fight Flu With Fruit""}";1;2663;;;;
```

And FinalCSVTestFin.csv :

```
url;urlid;boilerplate;alexarank
http://www.lynnskitchenadventures.com/2009/04/homemade-enchilada-sauce.html;5865;"{""title"":""Homemade Enchilada Sauce Lynn s Kitchen Adventures "",""body"":""I usually buy my enchilada sauce Yes I knew I should be making it but I had never found a recipe that I was really happy with I had tried several and they just weren t very good So I stuck to the canned stuff you can get at the grocery store I was recently talking to a friend of mine about this She lived in Mexico for a few years so she knows some about Mexican cooking I asked her how she made her enchilada sauce She told me the basics and then gave me an exact recipe I decided to give it a try This recipe was really good This was the best enchilada sauce that I have made It had great flavor I think it was even better than the canned sauce My husband thought it could have been spicier But he likes his enchiladas spicy You can always add more chili powder or chilies if you like it really spicy The kids and I thought it was really good just like it is I did change two things It called for green onions I did not have any so I used regular onions I thought they worked great so I will probably continue to make it this way I also pureed everything in the blender I wanted a very smooth sauce If you want it more chunky just mix the ingredients together and do not blend Enchiladas are a pretty frugal meal and homemade enchilada sauce is a great way to make enchiladas even more frugal 2 8 ounce cans tomato sauce 1 4 ounce can chopped green chilies undrained 1 2 cup onion chopped 2 teaspoons chili powder 1 teaspoon ground cumin 1 4 teaspoon dried oregano 1 clove garlic minced Combine all tomato sauce ingredients and place in a blender Puree ingredients Then place in a saucepan Heat over medium heat until heated through about 5 minutes Use as desired for enchiladas Get your free Quick Easy Breakfasts ebook Just subscribe for free email updates from Lynn s Kitchen Adventures Like this article Share it this homemade enchilada sauce recipe came from a friend of mine who spent several years in mexico."",""url"":""lynnskitchenadventures 2009 04 homemade enchilada sauce html""}";169088
http://lolpics.se/18552-stun-grenade-ar;782;"{""title"":""lolpics Stun grenade ar "",""body"":"" funny pictures at lolpics.se. the best funny images on the internet funny photo images, funny videos, can has cheezburger ,roliga bilder, lol pics, lolpics"",""url"":""lolpics se 18552 stun grenade ar""}";459983
```

I want to train on the TF-IDF column and the alexaranking column to produce a .csv file of answers but I am sure despite my best efforts I have made a number of errors here.

### Update

I am running the following code :

```
from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  import sklearn.preprocessing
  import sklearn.linear_model as lm
  import pandas as p
  loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=',')
  print "loading data.."
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])
  y = np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,-2]
  AlexaTrainData = p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]]
  AlexaTestData = p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]]
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaTestData.append(AlexaTrainData)
  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)
  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None)
  X_all = traindata + testdata
  lentrain = len(traindata)

  print "fitting pipeline"
  tfv.fit(X_all)
  print "transforming data"
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)
  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]
  print "X.shape => " + str(X.shape)
  print "AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape => " + str(AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape)
  print "X_all.shape => " + str(X_all.shape)
  #X = np.column_stack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
  X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
  sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
  X = sc.transform(X)
  X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Which produces the following output :

```
loading data..
fitting pipeline
transforming data
X.shape => (7395, 238377)
AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape => (7395, 1)
X_all.shape => (10566, 238377)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2b310887b5e4> in <module>()
     31 print "X_all.shape => " + str(X_all.shape)
     32 #X = np.column_stack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
---> 33 X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
     34 sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
     35 X = sc.transform(X)

C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.pyc in hstack(tup)
    271     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    272     if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 273         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    274     else:
    275         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: why are you reading the csvs, converting to numpy array and then to lists each time? There is a lot of noise here, unclear exactly where your question is.

Comment: @AndyHayden I am adapting some code which won a Kaggle competition so I can learn a bit and perhaps improve on it to teach myself machine-learning to some extent - those errors are remnants from this code where I simply don't 100% understand how to do what I want to do, so really this is what I would like help with. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Do you have a link to this code?

Comment: @AndyHayden The code is available here : http://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/forums/t/5680/beating-the-benchmark-leaderboard-auc-0-878 . The first post; I am simply trying to adapt this to include the second column :)

Comment: Which line is giving the ``ValueError``?

Comment: @YS-L I have updated my question with the line causing the error and more information on what is printed for the shape of each variable. Thank you :)

Comment: @SimonKiely There are two print shape statements, but three shapes are printed -- which corresponds to which? It'd be useful to check what exactly are the shapes of ``X`` and ``AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo`` just when ``np.hstack`` is called. The error message suggests that they are of different dimension -- meaning something like ``(7395,238377)`` vs ``(7395,)``.

Comment: @YS-L Thank you for the response, sorry for my ambiguity, I now print out all values explicitly which tells me that : `X.shape => (7395, 238377)`, `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape => (7395, 1)` and  `X_all.shape => (10566, 238377)`. Do you know how I might be able to fix this error? Many thanks for all the help.

Comment: @SimonKiely If that's the case I can't see the problem; the ``hstack`` should work fine. Moreover, the error message doesn't make sense as the number of dimensions of ``X`` and ``AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo`` are the same, based on your debug prints. Just to make sure, are you running the correct version of the code? From the error trace the lines of the debug prints weren't there.

Comment: @YS-L I have updated my code to show my debug prints and where they are printed - I haven't changed anything else though (unless I am overlooking something!). Thanks very much for having a look. Am I overlooking anything that you can see here?

Comment: @SimonKiely I think I found it -- try to use ``scipy.sparse.hstack`` instead of ``numpy.hstack``. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @YS-L Thank you for the response; unfortunately this now gives the error `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O'))
`

Comment: @SimonKiely should the solution work for the two csvs above, i.e. are they complete?

Comment: @AndyHayden It should, yes. Thank you! :)

Comment: dang it, not had time to get a solution for this. :(

Comment: @AndyHayden A similar question has been put here (with an even bigger bonty!) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117692/using-ranking-data-in-logistic-regression with some subtle differences, if you get some time  to have a look :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions I can give:

### Fixing the error thrown by `hstack`

Although the error message seems to suggest that `X` and `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo` have different dimensions, based on your debug prints they do have the same dimension. The problem is that `X` is a sparse matrix, try `scipy.sparse.hstack` instead of `numpy.hstack`.

### Order of training and test samples in the augmented column

The following code shows that in the augmented column, training samples comes after the testing samples.

```
AlexaTrainData = p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]] #reading integer columns
AlexaTestData = p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]]
AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaTestData.append(AlexaTrainData) #joining integer columns
```

Based on the arrangement of `X_all`, training samples comes before the testing samples. To make it the same for `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo`, I think you would actually want to do this instead:

```
AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaTrainData.append(AlexaTestData)
```

### Processing of `X_test` to include the new column

Moving on:

```
X = X_all[:lentrain]
AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo[:lentrain]
X_test = X_all[lentrain:]
X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X = sc.transform(X)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Here, you are truncating `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo` without updating `X_test` like you did using `hstack` with `X`. As a result, during the prediction stage,

```
pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

the model will complain that the given `X_test` has a different number of features compared to the training data. In fact, the error will happen even earlier when you do

```
sc.transform(X_test)
```